# How to test the outcome of a wpdb query?

Tags: post-meta, wpdb

I want to get all the data with the meta key of "project_id" from post meta table. I wrote a query, it should work in thoery, but I have no way to see what I get, and inject this query to my plugin doesn't generate anything. Please take a look at this query, and help me understand if it is correct, what's the formate of the outcome, How can I echo it to see what I get:

```
function mp_all_ids( ){
global $bp, $wpdb, $post;

$query = <<<QUERY
SELECT      project_id.post_id
FROM        $wpdb->postmeta project_id
LEFT JOIN  $wpdb->postmeta height 
            on height.post_id = project_id.post_id
            and height.meta_key = 'height'
LEFT JOIN  $wpdb->postmeta width 
            on width.post_id = project_id.post_id
            and width.meta_key = 'width' 
WHERE       project_id.meta_key = 'project_id'
ORDER BY    project_id.meta_value+(0) ASC
QUERY;
$data = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

return apply_filters( 'mp_ids', $data );
}
```

Edit:
the var_dump gets the following result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#457 (1) {
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(3) "385"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#458 (1) {
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(3) "451"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#377 (1) {
    ["post_id"]=>
    string(3) "453"
  }
}
```

How can I access the 3 strings in each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should look into using WP_Query for this:

http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html

Secondly, to see the results, just do a [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) before the return:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $data );
```

Comment: Thanks, @scribu! var_dump prints the result. Seems the query somewhat correct. Would you please take a look at the outcome(I'll pate it bellow the original question)and tell how to access the 3 strings in each object?

Comment: @scribu, thanks for the link to the query_post turorial. I might need that in later steps. For now, I need to query the object so that I can create a loop according to the ids, then, to display the objects on posts. please help!

Comment: You can use get_posts() instead of query_posts(). Not gonna help with the direct query. It's for your own good. :P

Comment: By the way, these are not really WordPress questions, but rather general PHP questions. You should read a couple of basic PHP tutorials before posting here.

Comment: If learned, we wouldn't come here for fast food, and that's not good for the QA site.

Comment: Didn't anyone tell you that fast food isn't healthy?

Comment: I eat decent meal regularly, but eat KFC sometimes when I visit unformiliar places. It would be strange if KFC suggested me to go to a nice resterant for a decent meal.

Comment: I guess the problem is that we're not trying to be KFC here. (That would be the wp.org support forums.) Don't know if we're succeeding. :-|

Comment: Demands and Supplies, that's what drives us. We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

To test if the query is working you could output the $query string that you have created and manually running that query on the wordpress database via PhpMyAdmin or a similar interface.

If there is any errors in the query or the query returns no results than you will be able to tweak it to get your desired effect before putting it in your code.

Comment: yes, how to output the $query string?